# Recursively Finding the Smallest Solution

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm working with a code that takes a list of numbers and calculates the lowest possible sum from that list recursively.  Here is my code so far:

```
def jumpIt(board, i):
  n = len(board)
  if i>n-1:
    return 0
  elif i+1>n-1:
    return board[i]
  else:
    if board[i]<board[i+1]:
        return board[i] + jumpIt(board,i+1)
    else:
        return board[i+1] + jumpIt(board,i+2)

def main():
  file = open("input.txt", "r")
  for line in file:
    numbers = line.split() 
    gameBoard = list(map(int, numbers))

    min_cost = jumpIt(gameBoard, 1)
    print(min_cost)
file.close()

main()
```

The code works by comparing the indices of two numbers in the list and adding whichever turns out to be the smaller one.  The issue I have is with a list of numbers like [0, 5, 10, 20, 2, 3].  My code currently calculates the cheapest cost to be 20 (5+10+2+3) when a better solution would be to skip the 5 and jump straight to 10, which would give me a sum of 15.  How do I alter my code to accommodate for a solution like that?

Comment: the lowest sum in `[ 0, 5, 10, 20, 2, 3 ]` is `0 + 2`, so is the answer `2` in this case? am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I can edit the post if need be, but this is in essence similar to the “Jump It” game.  With each step, it takes the two nearest numbers and picks one to add to the score, in this case, the lower number.  While that would be the lowest technically, it’s not a possible sum with those rules in mind.

Comment: An edit might be helpful. Perhaps you could show some more example inputs and their expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'm confused about why your call to `jumpIt` is starting on index 1 rather than 0. Please explain.

You seem to have implemented a "greedy" solution that assumes choosing the smaller of the two choice elements at each step will lead to the best. By doing this, we miss out on the potential power of recursion to answer our question, "which path is better?"

What we'd like to do instead is say, "we don't know which path is better, please tell me." We can do it like this:

Replace:

```
# I already know what's best
if board[i] < board[i+1]:
  return board[i] + jumpIt(board, i+1)
else:
  return board[i+1] + jumpIt(board, i+2)
```

with:

```
# I don't know which one is better, please tell me
return min(
  board[i] + jumpIt(board, i+1),
  board[i+1] + jumpIt(board, i+2)
)
```

Comment: The index was initially at 1 because each list in question began with 0 as the first value.     Your answer was just the thing I needed to know.   Thank you for the feedback, it was very much appreciated.